# Trouble Creating a Global Mutex

Tags: global, mutex

Testing on a Windows 10 Home edition.  When I attempt to create a global mutex of the form "GLOBAL\mutext name", I get error code 3.  I suspect that this may be because I am not running on a server-class machine.  However, Microsoft documentation says this should work even on my old XP Pro system.